# Getting model name for device in Bada

Tags: bada

I'm looking for an API call that will tell me wha kind of device the user has. For example: GT-S7250 or Wave M
Is there an API for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Getting the model name of a device in Bada 2.0 doesn’t have anything in the SDK documentation but can be accessed like this:

```
#include <FSysSystemInfo.h>

String deviceModel;
Osp::System::SystemInfo::GetValue(L”ModelName”, deviceModel);
AppLog(“Model Name %S”, deviceModel.GetPointer());
```

Also, remember to set the correct privilege in the manifest.xml

```
<Privilege>
<Name>SYSTEM_SERVICE</Name>
</Privilege>
```

It’s a bit worrisome that the [SystemInfo](http://developer.bada.com/help_2.0/topic/com.osp.cppappprogramming.help/html/dev_guide/system/sysinfo.htm) keys don’t list “ModelName” as a value key. Hopefully there won’t be any breaking changes.